# Get "id" values from first three tags only and separate them with "," in output

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a situation, hope experts here will help me to sort it out. I need to get "id" values for first three  tags and than on console.log print the values with comma separated.

I have managed to get the values from  tag and print it on output. However, I am not able to comma separate them, and the issue is I am getting id of all the number of articles rather than only 3.

This is the jquery code that I come up with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $("article").each(function() {
    var info1 = $(this).attr("id");
    var info2 = info1.replace( /[^\d]/g, '');
    console.log(info2);

});
});
```

And this is the test

```
http://jsfiddle.net/0mvjbkhs/1/
```

Please note that I am not able to do any changes to html, all I can do is to get things done using jquery.

Please help to fix my code, So my output will looks like 
**[155569, 155570, 155571]**

Thank you,

Comment: Use a counter in your `each` loop, so you can break out of it when you reach the third element. Put the ids into an array, and then use `Array.join` to get them as a comma separated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery `.map()` method which returns an array; if you need a single comma-delimited string, use the JavaScript `.join()` method. Don't forget `:lt(3)` which say you want the first three:

```
var arr1st3 = $('article:lt(3)').map(function() {
    return this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
}).get();
console.log( arr1st3 );//OUTPUT: ["155569", "155570", "155571"]
//If you want [155569, 155570, 155571] as output
//use return +this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); instead
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/0mvjbkhs/2/)

Comment: mate you are more than awesome, thanks alot.. all prayers are with you.

Comment: Glad I can be of help. Feel free to vote and accept this if you found it useful. Enjoy! :-)

Comment: A ***downvote*** only makes sense if there's a justifiable reason for it. Downvoter, feel free to explain your reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // search by the attribute 
  var ids = $('article')
    // Take only the first three items
    .slice(0, 3)
    // Loop them to return an array
    .each(function() {
      // Get just the id and put that in the array
      return this.attr('id');
    });

  // Format your output
  console.log('[' + ids.join(', ') + ']');
});
```

Comment: Dan I tried your code but it is having error "el.attr is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/0mvjbkhs/4/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var articles = [];

  $("article").each(function() {
    var info1 = $(this).attr("id").replace( /[^\d]/g, '');
    articles.push(info1);
    if (articles.length == 3) {
        // break;
        return false;
    }
  });
  console.log('[' + articles.join(', ') + ']');

});
```